# Is there any way to share data(not through cloud) between multiple users in lollipop nexus 4 device

Tags: nexus-4, 5.0-lollipop, multi-user

Is there any way to share data(not through cloud) between multiple users in lollipop nexus 4 device, I tried with android/obb and other folders but without any success in lollipop version. Kindly provide a way to share large files, within multiple users, on the same device.

Answer (score 5):

I think the first answer (by June Lau) misses the point - the question was about sharing files between different users on the SAME device. I have been using subdirectories that I created within android/obb with success. In my Nexus 7 tablet the exact path is /storage/emulated/0/Android/obb/. The issue is that the media browser does not see files in there, so that one needs to use some file-manager software (search for 'File Manager' in the play store) to get to the file and start its reproduction from there, or for moving the file into the user's file-system.

Comment: This worked for me on Android 7.1 as well. The second user was not seeing the obb folder, so I created it with no problem. When I opened it with the second user, I could see existing content (so it obviously hadn't been newly created, just somehow made visible through that action). Files dropped there were visible to the first user.

Comment: Confirm that many file handling/viewing apps ("File Picker" `com.android.documentsui`, "Gallery" `com.android.gallery3d` and their alternatives such as `com.simplemobiletools.filemanager.pro`, `com.simplemobiletools.gallery.pro` ) are programmed so badly as to ignore access to the obb shared files, needlessly complicating user->user data sharing, despite the way via `/data/obb` is indeed internally working and the correct way

Answer (score -1):

What sort of files are you trying to share? And how large are they?

Android beam / bluetooth will work, though it may take a while and not give you much feedback of how long it will take.

To do this, tap the 'three dots' on the top right, and select share. There's an option of 'android beam'. Make sure that the receiving phone has their nfc turned on.